# Tweaking excel formulas

Tags: microsoft-excel

Column A: Cost of an apple Column B: Quantity of apples purchased Column C: Total cost of apples purchased

Cell A2: $1.50 Cell B2: 3 Cell B3: 10 Cell B4: 15

C2 currently has the formula =A2*B2. How would I tweak the formula, so that when I drag down the formula to cells C3 and C4, A2 stays the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use absolute cell reference with cost - **$A$2** instead of **A2**

`=$A$2*B2`

Now when you drag the formula down, it will change to look like this:

```
=$A$2*B3
=$A$2*B4
etc
```